# Action in AdS/CFT correspondence

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, ads-cft, duality

I am a beginner trying to study AdS/CFT correspondence.

Could someone please explain, can we connect action in the gravity side to the field theory side by this correspondence?  Can we write the action of a conformal field theory at the boundary in terms of bulk variables?

Comment: The action on the gravity side lets you define the path integral $Z[\varphi] = \int_{\varphi} \exp \left ( i S[\phi] \right ) D \phi$ where the subscript means we integrate over functions $\phi(x, z)$ such that $\phi(x, 0) = \varphi(x)$. AdS / CFT says that $Z[\varphi] = \left < \exp \left ( i \int \varphi \mathcal{O} \right ) \right >$ which is the object in the CFT whose derivatives yield correlators of $\mathcal{O}$. This generating functional can be written in terms of an action when the CFT has one, but this is usually not the case.

Comment: So what you say is, we can't equate or connect action on the boundary to the bulk, isn't it @Connor Behan

Comment: Yes. A good exercise is to solve for the boundary theory of a free massless scalar, not in $AdS_{d + 1}$ but in $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}_+$. This will already not have a local Lagrangian.